# Two closest points in Manhattan distance

Tags: algorithms

I'm wondering about Manhattan distance. It is very specific, and (I don't know if it's a good word) simple. For example when we are given a set of $n$ points in this metric, then it is very easy to find the distance between two farthest points, in $O(n)$ time. But is it also easy to find two closest points?

I heard, that there exists universal algorithm for finding two closest points in any metric, but it's complicated. I'm wondering if in this situation (Manhattan metric) it is possible to use special properties of this distance and come up with an easier algorithm, that will be more friendly in implementation?

$n$ points on a plane, and lets say $-10^9 \le x,y \le 10^9$ for all points.

Comment: How do you compute the distance between two farthest points?

Comment: @Brainstorming, firstly I find max $x$, max $y$, min $x$, min $y$ so I've got 4 points creating minimum rectangle containing all $n$ points. Then I search for $4$ points that are closest to each rectangle's vertices. Then I check all pairs from those $4$ points. At least one pair is what I'm searching for. With a bit of work it can be proved that it is correct. Complexity is obvious, four loops give $O(n)$.